# Obtener columna en consulta con serie de numeros sin usar row_number

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

acudo a ustedes porque tengo una consulta en la cual por problemas de compatibilidad no puedo usar la funcion row_number(). Me dijeron que quizá podía usar una función con un counter, pero no sé como aplicar esa funcionalidad. Esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT fecha::date, row_number() over (ORDER BY fecha)
FROM generate_series(NOW()::date + 1, NOW()::date +30 * 7, '1 day'::interval) fecha
WHERE extract ('dow' FROM fecha) NOT IN (0,6)
AND fecha NOT IN (SELECT f.fecha FROM dblink(dblink_config(),
'SELECT fecha FROM public.feriado WHERE fecha >= current_date') AS f(fecha DATE))
```

De la cual obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Espero esta **[liga](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/get-row-number-postgresql/)** te ayude, es el último ejemplo.

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias, me ayudó muchísimo. Dejaré la modificación de la query por si a alguien le sirve

Answer (score 4):

Un compañero de esta red me pasó un link donde pude ver un ejemplo de como aplicar una solución. Dejaré la respuesta por si le sirve a alguien

```
SELECT count(*) rownum, fecha.*::date FROM generate_series(NOW()::date + 1, NOW()::date +30 * 7, '1 day'::interval) fecha
JOIN generate_series(NOW()::date + 1, NOW()::date +30 * 7, '1 day'::interval) bar
ON (fecha >= bar) WHERE extract ('dow' FROM fecha) NOT IN (0,6) AND extract ('dow' FROM bar) NOT IN (0,6) AND fecha NOT IN (SELECT f.fecha FROM dblink(dblink_config(),
'SELECT fecha FROM public.feriado WHERE fecha >= current_date') AS f(fecha DATE)) AND bar NOT IN (SELECT f.fecha FROM dblink(dblink_config(),'SELECT fecha FROM public.feriado WHERE fecha >= current_date') AS f(fecha DATE))GROUP BY  fecha ORDER BY  rownum
```